# How to get from an integer day value day as string

Tags: c#, dayofweek

I stored into my database as integer day values.
From a string array I was getting the day as string.

```
public static string[] _dayofweek = new string[] {"SUNDAY","MONDAY","TUESDAY","WEDNESDAY","THURSDAY","FRIDAY","SATURDAY"};
```

However, now I want to get the name of day relatively to cultureinfo not only as fixed in english.

Is it possible to get the names of week from this stored day number ?

Comment: What do you mean by _"the name of day relatively to cultureinfo not only as fixed in english"_? Should day 0 always return the first day of the week in the current culture, in English? See [CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.firstdayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I stored only numbers. 0= sunday, 1= monday as in my _dayofweek variable. When I read the number from data I was getting the day from this variable. I would display the day not only in english but with selected culture on the computer. Fixed in english-> _dayofweek(my variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `ToString("dddd")` on a `DateTime`. I would pick an arbitrary Sunday and use `AddDays` to translate your index.

```
int _dayOfWeek = 1; //Monday
string weekdayString = new DateTime(2015, 4, 12).AddDays(_dayOfWeek)
                                                .ToString("dddd");
                     // ^ "Monday" or whatever locale you are in
```

Comment: Thanks it was so usefull. I stored with Sunday as zero in m database  and as you advise I added this numbers to a fixed sunday date. So now I can get with the currentcultur.